# Can't run Parity: "Failed to create lock file, the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: parity

trying to run parity, I get the following  error:

```
Client  service error: Client(Database("IO error: Failed  to create lock file:        C:\\Users\\mjensen01\AppData\\Local\\Parity\\Ethereum\\chains\\ethereum\\db\\906a34e69aec8c0d\\overlayrecent\\db/LOCK:  The process cannot access the file because  it is being used by another process.\r\n"))
```

I ran the windows  executable from here:  https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases, then navigated to the directory where  it got installed, and put in parity --warp, as explained here:  https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Getting-Synced.  It seems there are some instructions missing?  ...

Comment: this is bizare.  I just opened parity again using a generated token from the command-line, and I notice "warp restore" at the bottom of the screen, with an increasing percentage.  so I have to conclude that the warp restore is actually working, which could explain the error message.  this would imply that the instructions I followed are just out of date?  if somebody could confirm this diagnostic, that would be nice. :-)

Comment: The error message you mention probably means that Parity is already running. It would only be running if you'd already started it. Find the process in the task manager and either kill it and start it again or, if it's already running as you want, leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your node is already running. You will see the parity tray icon.

If you don't want it to run automatically, you can right-click on the tray icon and remove the tick at "run at startup".

Note the `--warp` flag does nothing as it is enabled by default.